# Difference between statvfs() and statfs() system calls?

Tags: c, linux, mount, vfs

Why do the [`statfs()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/statfs/) and [`statvfs()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/statvfs/) calls both exist when they're so similar?

Under what circumstances would I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Err, "historical reasons".

Originally 4.4BSD defined a `statfs()` call. Linux later implemented a slightly different call with the same name. Posix standardized it between all freenix and Unix versions by defining `statvfs()`.

`statfs()` is OS-specific

`statvfs()` is posix-conforming

As they all return slightly different structures, later ones to come along can't replace the first.

In general you should use `statvfs()`, the Posix one.  Be careful about "use Posix"  advice, though, as in some cases (pty, for example) the BSD (or whatever) one is more portable in practice.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want file system capacity and usage information, the other answers are correct: prefer `statvfs` because it is standard POSIX and handles large file sizes better. `statfs` is BSD- and Linux-specific, with different structures on each. (Linux 2.6 added new `statfs64` and `fstatfs64` system calls that use an expanded structure to handle larger sizes.) However, **`statfs` is still useful on Linux for determining the file system type** (assuming you're okay with writing Linux-specific code).

Answer (score 1):

`statfs()` is deprecated in favor of `statvfs()`, which deals *considerably* better with large file support. `statfs()` is known to do odd things for sizes that exceed the value of an unsigned long.

As far as I can tell (and remember), `statvfs()` has been around since Redhat 7.3, just after being introduced as a POSIX replacement. You'll likely find it on (most) modern systems.

Comment: I don't understand how a system call (statfs) would be deprecated in favor of a library call (statvfs).  They have different purposes and using statfs in application code might be deprecated but I think that's worth qualifying.  Currently glibc-2.25 appears to call statfs.